# C++ define argument overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

I've written simple logger for unified logging in my library.
What I have now:

```
enum LogLevel {
    DEBUG,
    INFO,
    WARNING,
    ERROR
};

//this calls vfprintf(...)
void Log( LogLevel level, const char * format, ...);

//compile time log string concatenation, if logs should be disabled define NO_LOGS during compilation
#ifndef NO_LOGS
    #define LOG(LEVEL, MSG, ...) Log(LEVEL, "[" #LEVEL "] " MSG "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define LOG(LEVEL, MSG, ...)
#endif

//defines for fast logging
#define LOGD(MSG, ...) LOG(DEBUG, MSG, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(MSG, ...) LOG(INFO, MSG, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(MSG, ...) LOG(WARNING, MSG, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(MSG, ...) LOG(ERROR, MSG, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

This is awesome but I have one problem with it. While calling `LOGI("log value %d", value)` works as expects, it's not possible to call `LOGI("simple log msg")` instead I have to call `LOGI("%s","simple log msg")`which just looks awful. Is it possible to solve this problem in defines? I've tried a following code but it doesn't compile since define overloading based on arguments is not possible in C++.

```
#define LOGD(MSG, ...) LOG(DEBUG, MSG, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(MSG) LOG(DEBUG, "%s", MSG)
```

I know I can easily solve this by using normal functions overloading, but I really want to have logging system with minimal overhead hence usage of defines that allow me to concatenate strings in compile time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why doesn't 
#define LOGI(x)  LOG(INFO, "%s", x)
work?

Comment: `#define LOGI(...) LOG(INFO, __VA_ARGS__)`?

Comment: @Shark because it's redefining previous macro `LOGI(MSG, ...)`
@melpomene this would redefine `LOGI(MSG,...)`

Comment: If you used inline functions instead of macros, they could be overloaded...

Comment: I believe @melpomene meant to replace `#define LOGI(MSG, ...)` with his/her suggestion. `LOGI("log value %d", value)` then becomes `Log(INFO,"log value %d", value)` and `LOGI("simple log msg")` becomes `Log(INFO, "simple log msg")`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of the input arguments inside the `Log` function. If there are none, you just use `fputs` instead of `vfprintf`.

Comment: That would require to count elements in a loop before printing them. It is too much overhead for a simple logging function. I had another idea right now, do you think it would be possible with variadic templates?

Comment: Yes, it might work. Also consider using streams instead of `printf` like in Boost.Logging library. Using: `LOGI << "Param1="<< int_val << ", param2="<< float_val << ", descr="<< str_val;`